# Vim, ctags and polymorphism

Tags: c++, vim, polymorphism, ctags

Is there a way to make vim jump to the right matching definition AUTOMATICALLY in case of multiple definitions. Our C++ code heavily uses polymorphism and vim's handling of ctags does not seems to be ready for polymorphism.

For example,

```
void abc(int a, int b) {

}

void abc(int a, int b, int c) {

}
```

Strangely, ctrl-] on

```
abc(1,2,3);
```

takes to the 1st definition and not the correct definition which is 2nd. Also, g-] prompts for options but that's not what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, this is not polymorphism. That aside: Parsing C++ is fairly hard, so you probably need a plugin like ycm for this.

Comment: What about asking this question on [a vim stackexchange site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: thanks, will post there.